# ASP.NET Downloading exported excel sheet sometimes renders the source page itselft

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, export-to-excel

I have two reports that download excel files when the user clicks the export button. Both of them use the same method in an external library (shown below). One of the reports opens the excel sheet normally with the generated data while the other shows the source page design inside the excel sheet. This happens in VS2008.
What is going on, and how to solve it?

```
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel;";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Report.xls");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "utf-8";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(@"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"">");

            //sets font
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<font style='font-size:10.0pt; font-family:Calibri;'>");

            if (addCurrentDate)
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<h5 align='left'>" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "</h5>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<h2>" + title + "</h2>");

            string subttitlesString = string.Empty;
            if (subItems != null && subItems.Count > 0)
            {
                subttitlesString = "<table>";
                foreach (var item in subItems)
                {
                    subttitlesString += string.Format("<tr><td style='font-weight:bold;'>{0}</td><td>{1}</td></tr>", item.Key, item.Value);
                }
                subttitlesString += "</table>";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(subttitlesString);
            }

            //sets the table border, cell spacing, border color, font of the text, background, foreground, font height
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Table border='1' bgColor='#ffffff' " +
              "borderColor='#000000' cellSpacing='0' cellPadding='0' " +
              "style='font-size:10.0pt; font-family:Calibri; background:white;'> <TR>");

            //am getting my grid's column headers
            int columnscount = table.Columns.Count;

            for (int j = 0; j < columnscount; j++)
            {      //write in new column
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Td>");
                //Get column headers  and make it as bold in excel columns
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<B>");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(table.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToString());
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</B>");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Td>");
            }

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</TR>");
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {//write in new row
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<TR>");
                for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Td>");
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(row[i].ToString());
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Td>");
                }

                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</TR>");
            }

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Table>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</font>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

[image: The excel sheet being exported:]

Comment: you are using this same method for downloading both files right?

Comment: Well you're printing HTML and calling it Excel. While this usually works, if it doesn't, you're on your own. Compare the working and not working HTML. It's probably got to do with mismatched tags or other invalid HTML.

Comment: Both reports call the same method.

Comment: I don't think it matters, but the working report page is C# while the other not working one is VB

Comment: The users are not actually downloading excel files here, just html that is trying to pretend it is excel. I would suggest to just download the actual files or if they are generated on the fly look for a third party library like [EPPLus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) to generate the excel file on the fly and let the user download that. This idea of trying to generate html that excel will try to interpret is imho not a good solution.

Comment: OK thanks i will look more into EPP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of this, which is quite obvious now.
The calling event of the above exporting method has two catch sections:

1. ThreadAbortException
2. Exception

The ThreadAbortException part had Thread.ResetAbort() because the ThreadAbortException keeps re-throwing itself. This seems to reset all the HTTPRespnse content that was previously added.

Answer (score 1):

Is this code surrounded by try-catch? May be for code that is rendering source page, you are getting exception somewhere, which is resulting in HTML of source page being rendered. Any ways, why are you writing HTML as application/ms-excel?

Comment: It is surrounded by try-catch. I was only getting the ThreadAbortException but for both reports. Regarding your second question: I needed a way to export data to excel while having the ability to customize the excel sheet a bit without the need for excel to be installed. I found it on the net

Comment: Then some additional details like signature of this function and code that is calling it, will be helpful.